# Can I publish Asset library 'Thumbnails.aspx' page to anonymous users?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, publishing, video, video-richmedia

I have site on publishing template, created Asset Library video App

[image]

put videos and thumbnail there, and now I want to publish this page to external anonymous users. But there is no "Publish" tab in ribbon, and "Approve/Reject" items are greyed-out:

[image]
 Other pages(that I created in "Pages" lib - coulb be edited and published), anonymous is enabled. I thought it could be becouse of thumbnails permissions, I don't know if they inherited 'Anonymous'.. but I think in that case Fiddler would show 'permission denied' on specifically thumbnail picture, but it gives access denied accessing whole library:

[image]

Could video asset app be published at all?

**Update:** I have tried to activate "Wiki Page Home Page" site Feature, like described [here](http://wikiwizdom.com/?p=59), but no result

Answer (score 0):

The answer - it is about "Limited-access user permission" Site collection Feature. This standard feature is designed to block access to "Site content" and other application pages for anonymous users, but as far as I understand - it also blocks access to Forms folder, which is used by Asset library app

[image]

Once deactivated, access to anonymous users restore